# Matplotlib/Seaborn: how to plot a rugplot on the top edge of x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose I draw a plot using the code below. How to plot the rug part on the top edge of x-axis?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100), rug=True, hist=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `seaborn.rugplot` creates a `LineCollection` with the length of the lines being defined in axes coordinates. Those are always the same, such that the plot does not change if you invert the axes.

You can create your own `LineCollection` from the data though. The advantage compared to using `bar`s is that the linewidth is in points and therefore no lines will be lost independend of the data range.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def upper_rugplot(data, height=.05, ax=None, **kwargs):
    from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    kwargs.setdefault("linewidth", 1)
    segs = np.stack((np.c_[data, data],
                     np.c_[np.ones_like(data), np.ones_like(data)-height]),
                    axis=-1)
    lc = LineCollection(segs, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), **kwargs)
    ax.add_collection(lc)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100)
sns.distplot(data, rug=False, hist=False, ax=ax)

upper_rugplot(data, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Rugs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html) are just thin lines at the data points. Yo can think of them as thin bars. That being said, you can have a following work around: Plot `distplot` without rugs and then create a twin x-axis and plot a bar chart with **thin bars**. Following is a working answer:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(21)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 100)
sns.distplot(data, rug=False, hist=False, ax=ax)

ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.bar(data, height=ax.get_ylim()[1]/10, width=0.001)
ax1.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your answer, because this seems to be the right way to do it. That being said, it doesn't yield an identical rugplot (I set the seed to 21 like you did in order to compare the results). They are very close, but not identical. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: (I also get my seaborn answers downvoted frequently; and I think I know who does it, but not why.) Anyways, I think you could directly plot a `rugplot` on the inverted twin axes, right?

Comment: @VictorValente: My data looks like `[-0.00519642 -0.01111961  0.10417968 -0.12567393  0.07453877 -0.17110538
 -0.02058644 -0.02345713  0.1128144  -0.0012626  -0.06132003  0.13736885....`. Do you also have the same array of numbers?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Specifically I tried `ax1 = ax.twiny()`; `sns.rugplot(data, ax=ax1)`; `ax1.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())` but the rugplot was still on the bottom x-axis

Comment: @Bazingaa yes, same array here. You can check that `data[82]` is plotted by the sns default method, but is not plotted by yours. I have no idea why that happens.

Comment: @Bazingaa It seem to be a question of bar width. I tried `width=0.002` and the bar for `data[82]` appeared. It is still not identical, but I think this is the reason.

Comment: @VictorValente: Yes, this could be the reason because the numbers are so close